# Can't build python_orocos_kdl on OSX

Tags: ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Have this problem while compiling all the packages on OSX:

```
ros_ws/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/python_orocos_kdl/cmake/FindSIP.py", line 8, in <module>
  import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named sipconfig
CMake Error at cmake/FindSIP.cmake:54 (MESSAGE):
Could not find SIP
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54234/can%27t-build-python_orocos_kdl-on-osx/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sip is not on your `PYTHONPATH` most likely.

See the Caveat for sip:

```
$ brew info sip
sip: stable 4.13.3, HEAD
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip
/usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.13.3 (9 files, 600K) *
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/sip.rb
==> Caveats
For non-homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

This Caveat is where this step of the Homebrew install instructions come from:

http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#Setup_Environment

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should solve it

> ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.21/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py

---

Originally posted by [pfj](https://answers.ros.org/users/53143/pfj/) with karma: 11 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jell](https://answers.ros.org/users/61206/jell/) on 2020-10-18**:
This worked for me.